# Snap SVG: odd behaviour when composing negative scale and translate transformations

Tags: snap.svg

I'm experimenting with snapSVG and I'm trying to flip a 100x200 rectangle vertically.

After I flipped it with scale(-1,1) the rectangle went off the screen (to the left), so I added a translate(100,0) to bring it back, but it just moved further away to the left:

```js
var r1 = s.rect(0, 0, 100, 200);
console.log(r1.getBBox().x + " * " + r1.getBBox().x2); // gives 0 * 100
r1.transform("scale(-1,1) translate(100,0)");
console.log(r1.getBBox().x + " * " + r1.getBBox().x2); // gives -200 * -100
```

Turns out that to bring it back I need a translate(-100,0); it seems like the "negative scaling" has flipped the x-axis coordinate system, too.
Here's an example, I would expect to see the blue rectangle, but I see the red one, instead:
https://codepen.io/dsotr/pen/WjRLaV

Am I missing something?

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transform, you change the whole coordinate space, so following transforms will be affected by that. A negative scale of -1 will effectively mirror it. So now when you translate x by 100, it will move in the opposite direction.

If you want to flip it vertically, scale it by 's1,-1' (or 's-1,1' if you wanted to flip it on the other axis). If you use Snaps transform string notation, it will scale from the center as well. If you use scale(x,y) then it will scale from a default of 0,0 which is typically not what you want.

If you want to translate and scale it, translate it first, and then scale it. In Snaps transform string notation it would be...

```
r1.transform('t100,0s1,-1');
```